# backbonejs output toggles after every refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to run [this code](https://github.com/hegdeashwin/Backbone/blob/master/codes/Ch3_View_Events_Templates/Ch3_1_View/Example1/example-main-1.js). Every time I refresh, the following code

```
console.log(childView.el);
```

output toggles between this

```
<div id="master" class="container"></div>
```

and this:

```
div#master.container
```

I would like to understand why this toggles. Here is a gif of what I see (take a look at the console).

[image]

Comment: This is probably a chrome thing... Did you try a different browser..?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Chrome has two different ways of displaying an element in the console: the "DOM way" and the "Javascript way".  I believe what you are seeing is Chrome rendering the element one way initially, then switching to the other representation right after (ie. you're seeing a minor bug in the developer tools).

Answer (score 0):

I think that @machineghost is right, this is a bug in developer tools. The "correct" output is the DOM notation: `<div id="master" class="container"></div>`. However, when the view instance is created, the `.el` property is resolved from a selector string to a DOM element. The other notation you are seeing is the selector string for the created view.

Though the selector string is used in while creating the instance of the View, the `el` property is always set to a DOM element, every time, using a detached `<div>` if no other option is provided.